# Bootstrap Modal Popup not working with Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, listview, updatepanel

I have a listview which has a child element(a button) which opens a modal popup upon click. After i add an Update Panel the pop up does not work.

The popup has some fields which when updated should refresh the listview. Tried placing it outside & inside the update panel, nothing seem to work.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack!  If you provide some code that you tested its easier to get help, its easier for every one to understand what you done and tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a  ModalPopupExtender and have this refer to a Panel which contains your bootstrap modal markup.

Try this for starters. [ModalPopupExtender example](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)